# ModuleParse Failed or Not Found

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, twilio

I am building a web app that allows users to type in phone numbers and send text messages via the Twilio API. I've built the functionality in a file, shown below. If I `cd` to this file and run `node twilioActions.js`, the text message gets sent.

```
var client = require('twilio')(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);

// ideally, I'd like to send the message using this method and call this from other JavaScript files
export const sendMessage = () => {

}

// the following code works when I run 'node twilioActions.js'
client.sendMessage({
  to:'...', 
  from: '...', 
  body: 'Text message test.' 
}, function(err, responseData) { 
  if (!err) { 
    console.log(responseData.from); // outputs "+14506667788"
    console.log(responseData.body); // outputs "word to your mother."
  }
});
```

However, I want to call the `sendMessage` method from a different React file. Here is it:

```
import * as twilioActions from './twilioActions';

class PhoneView extends React.Component{
  // other methods are hidden obviously, the one below is called when a button is pressed to send a message.
  sendMessage() {
    twilioActions.sendMessage();
  }
}
```

When I try to build the project, I get the following errors:

```
ERROR in ./~/twilio/package.json
Module parse failed:/Users/Felix/Desktop/ECE590/node_modules/twilio/package.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "_args": [
|     [
|       "twilio",
 @ ./~/twilio/lib/Client.js 5:17-43

ERROR in ./~/request/lib/har.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Felix/Desktop/ECE590/node_modules/request/lib
 @ ./~/request/lib/har.js 3:9-22

ERROR in ./~/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in /Users/Felix/Desktop/ECE590/node_modules/tunnel-agent
 @ ./~/tunnel-agent/index.js 3:10-24

ERROR in ./~/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'tls' in /Users/Felix/Desktop/ECE590/node_modules/tunnel-agent
@ ./~/tunnel-agent/index.js 4:10-24
```

I feel like I am making a simple mistake and perhaps am not using the correct libraries or including the proper references. Could someone point me in the right direction about how to get this to work? Thank you so much!

Comment: What are you using to build the project? Webpack? It sounds like you don't have a transpiler like Babel set up and configured to handle the ES2015 in your build step.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The twilio npm module is not built or recommended for use in the front end. The main thing is that you would need to expose your account credentials in the front end code of your site. This is a security risk as it means a malicious attacker could get hold of your credentials and abuse your Twilio account.

I recommend creating a service on your server side that you can call to with an AJAX request in order to perform actions like this.